# Need to close an open pop up and navigate to an URL

Tags: javascript

I am new at scripting and am lost.

I have a page that calls a popup in two places by this link:

```
Click <a href=""


onclick="window.open('poptest.php','chat_popup','toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,width=400,height=400'); return false;">here</a> for the pop-up Chat window only.
```

Also on the page is a link to this window.location.href command:

```
<button onclick="goto()">Back to the Intro Page</button>
<script>

    function goto() {
        window.location.href="http://www.streamcasters.com/temchat/sidebyside.html";
    }
    </script>
```

Users are not closing the popup before using the window.location.href command.Is there a dual-command where when a user clicks the location script it ALSO closes the specific onclick=window.open tab (the popup that might be left open when they go to a page where the formatting is different)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the opened window in a variable, and use that variable to close the window when the time comes

- Create a global variable, say `popup`. Normally, global variables are a sign of poor design, but, in this case, you will need to access the same variable from more than one place.
- Rather than go straight into the `window.open`, take advantage of the fact that the method contains a return result. So, `popup = window.open(…)`.
- Use the `beforeunload` event to close the window

Something like this:

```js
var popup;
popup = window.open(…);
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(popup) popup.close();
};
```